# Changing a image of a picturebox in form 1 from form2

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I made a program where I need to change my Picturebox in Form1. This needs to happen in the 2nd form(Form2)

Form2:

```
private void btnBrowseFirstAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tbFirstAdBlock.Text = OFD.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void btnChangeFirstAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        Form1 Screen = new Form1();

        Screen.changePB(tbFirstAdBlock.Text);
    }
```

Form1

```
    public void changePB(string PBLocation)
    {
        pbAddOne.Image = Image.FromFile(PBLocation);
    }
```

Sadly the picturebox isn't changing.

Comment: Yes it is but you don't see it because it is changing on the newly created form1, which you don't show.. You need to use a handle to form1 and call the function on it. You can search for it or try to find out for yourself how to pass the form1 reference in the constructor  of form2 to form2 and store it there in the constructor in a form2 class variable..

Answer (score 0):

In Form2 you need to have link to Form1:

```
class Form2
{
  public Form1 form1;
.....
 private void btnChangeFirstAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        form1.changePB(tbFirstAdBlock.Text);
        form1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

....

```
void Main()
    {
       Form1 Screen =new Form1();
       Form2 Screen1 =new Form2();
       Screen1.form1=Screen;
    }
```

....